# Is the option to create a Workspace available in Microsoft Visual C++ Express?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm new in C++ and its IDE. I'm learning it from a guide that indicates me it would be better to have a workspace where I could save projects in it. I would like to know if this option still exists or maybe is not available in Visual C++ Express. If not appearing, which other method would be suitable?

Comment: Erm... download codeblocks, its a really nice c++ ide... and umm... study more c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the sense of Eclipse workspaces no. Visual Studio deals with a solution (and only one at a time), which is a set of projects grouped together.

If I recall correctly, the Express versions only allow one project at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 6 and earlier grouped projects (.dsp files) into workspaces (.dsw files). Workspaces have been replaced by solution files (.sln) since Visual Studio.NET (ca. 2001). Incidentally .dsp files were replaced by .vcproj and now .vcxproj files. Your guide may be outdated if it is talking about workspaces.